# React state not changing on input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm trying to build a simple login/signup form using React, Typescript (my first usage of it), and AntDesign.
So here's my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Typography, Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';
const { Title } = Typography;


interface Props {
}

interface State {
    email: string,
    password: string
}

export class Login extends Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
                        email: '',
                        password: ''
                    }
    }

    handleChange = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>):void => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;
        this.setState({ [name] : value } as Pick<State, keyof State> );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Title level={2}>Log In</Title>
                <Form  className='login-form'>
                    <Form.Item>
                        <Input size='large' placeholder='E-mail used during registration' name='email' onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                        <Input size='large' type='password' placeholder='Password' name='password' onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                        <Button size='large' type='primary' block>
                            Log In
                        </Button>
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is that input doesn't change the state.
In `React Devtools` the state is shown unchanged, but `undo` sign appears.

Comment: Out of this question, you are using uncontrolled components, so there is no need to setState. Or you should use controlled components.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried popping it into my project quickly. Try changing your structure to this:

```
    ....
    state: State = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }

    handleChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;
        this.setState({ [name]: value } as Pick<State, keyof State>, () => console.log(this.state));
    }
    ....
```

Basically I just removed the constructor, and set the state directly and typed it.
Notice I used the `setState()` callback hook to check if the state actually updates.

Render:
[image: The App]

And the console log:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Actually, it does work.
There must be something wrong with Chrome Devtools. I tried to `console.log(this.state)` onBlur, and it does give the expected results.

Comment: You can delete the question if there was nothing to be learned for anyone from this question.